# classes not found achartengine

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, achartengine

So i've been trying to implement achart engine for android into my project but i have some slight complications that i don't really know how to resolve, The first problems DDMS points out before the fatal exception is that i cannot find the classes that are defined in the library for achart engine, i've imported the library jar using user libraries in eclipse. The fatal exception points out a 'NoClassDefFoundException' on the class 'PointStyle'. How can i resolve this ?

Comment: There is another question that answers this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160778/the-application-achartengine-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again

Answer (score 3):

Follow below steps that might prevent you from this error:

1) Open "Properties" of "Achartengine" project.(This can open from right click on project)

2) Select Java Build Path.

3) Select Order and Export and select achartengine jar file.

4) Then press OK

This steps resolve my problem , So I hope also resolve yours.