# The application AChartengine has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, achartengine

I just tried to use achartengine demo, but every time I click on something to show the chart appears an error saying "The application AChartengine has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". Someone knows to tell me how can I do? I followed the instructions suggested in this page http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html and I use an emulator standard with api level 7. I have these errors:

```
    04-15 09:08:43.285: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AverageTemperatureChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.325: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.XYSeries', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.addXYSeries
    04-15 09:08:43.345: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildBarDataset
    04-15 09:08:43.387: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildBarRenderer
    04-15 09:08:43.395: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildCategoryDataset
    04-15 09:08:43.425: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildCategoryRenderer
    04-15 09:08:43.425: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildDataset
    04-15 09:08:43.445: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildDateDataset
    04-15 09:08:43.445: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.MultipleCategorySeries', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildMultipleCategoryDataset
    04-15 09:08:43.485: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AbstractDemoChart.buildRenderer
    04-15 09:08:43.525: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AverageCubicTemperatureChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.545: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.TrigonometricFunctionsChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.555: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.ScatterChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.555: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.SalesComparisonChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.565: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.ProjectStatusChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.576: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.SalesGrowthChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.595: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.ProjectStatusBubbleChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.606: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.TemperatureChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.606: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.WeightDialChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.615: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.SensorValuesChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.615: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.CombinedTemperatureChart.execute
    04-15 09:08:43.626: E/dalvikvm(333): Could not find class '[Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;', referenced from method org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.MultipleTemperatureChart.execute
    04-15 09:13:51.145: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.AverageTemperatureChart.execute(AverageTemperatureChart.java:72)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.ChartDemo.onListItemClick(ChartDemo.java:102)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:312)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    04-15 09:13:51.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-15 09:13:51.175: E/dalvikvm(333): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: is this full log cat or i think missed something from logcat error log

Comment: you're right the whole log is the one I re-posted just now.

Comment: can you show how you are using it some code which you wrote and have you add the achartengine jar file in libs folder.

Comment: I was trying to use Achartengine Demo just because I wanted to understand how acharengine works...

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842537/unable-to-open-stack-trace-file-data-anr-traces-txt-permission-denied

Comment: also since you are using achatengine jar you must add these activity in your manifest file <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See this for a solution to this:
http://groups.google.com/group/achartengine/browse_thread/thread/4cb1efddad3c19d0/2b59e5164e05c469#2b59e5164e05c469

Dan

Quote:

> In Eclipse: 
>    -> Right click your project - go to build path - select Configure build path 
>    -> go to the "Order and Export" tab 
>    -> Check the "achartengine-1.0.0.jar box and then single click its name 
>    -> move it up so its right below the Android dependancies (sometimes this 
>    can make a difference if you have multiple Jars)
>
> click ok then clean your project. (Project -> Clean...)
>
> Try running it again and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I just used your quote and fixed the issue - bonus points for brevity :)

Comment: +1 for the link. **From the thread:**, If it is in directory by the name of `lib`, rename that to `libs` or anything else, and re-add the build path.

Comment: I moved it to the top just below src. Worked.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know how achartengine work then add the achartengine 0.7.0 jar to libs folder and link it with your project also have these below activity.

```
public class GeneratedChartDemo extends ListActivity {
  private static final int SERIES_NR = 2;

  private String[] mMenuText;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // I know, I know, this should go into strings.xml and accessed using
    // getString(R.string....)
    mMenuText = new String[] { "Line chart", "Scatter chart", "Time chart", "Bar chart" };
   setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, getListValues(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        new String[] { "name"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));
  }

  private List<Map<String, String>> getListValues() {
    List<Map<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    int length = mMenuText.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      Map<String, String> v = new HashMap<String, String>();
      v.put("name", mMenuText[i]);
      values.add(v);
    }
    return values;
  }

  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 10;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
      XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
      for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
        series.add(k, 20 + r.nextInt() % 100);
      }
      dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
    return dataset;
  }

  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDateDemoDataset() {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 10;
    long value = new Date().getTime() - 3 * TimeChart.DAY;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
      TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
      for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
        series.add(new Date(value + k * TimeChart.DAY / 4), 20 + r.nextInt() % 100);
      }
      dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
    return dataset;
  }

  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDemoDataset() {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 10;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
      CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
      for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
        series.add(100 + r.nextInt() % 100);
      }
      dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    }
    return dataset;
  }

  private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);    
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    r.setFillBelowLine(true);
    r.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.WHITE);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
  renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "aga");
  renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "agar");
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    return renderer;
  }

  public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarDemoRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
    SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    return renderer;
  }

  private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
    renderer.setChartTitle("Chart demo");
    renderer.setXTitle("x values");
    renderer.setYTitle("y values");
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(5);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(250);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
      Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(this, getDemoDataset(), getDemoRenderer());
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
    case 1:
      intent = ChartFactory.getScatterChartIntent(this, getDemoDataset(), getDemoRenderer());
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
    case 2:
      intent = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(this, getDateDemoDataset(), getDemoRenderer(), null);
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
    case 3:
      XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getBarDemoRenderer();
      setChartSettings(renderer);
      intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, getBarDemoDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```