# Unable to use chart libraries in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, charts

**Can any one please tell me how to create a bar-chart in Android?**

After I did some searches on Google then I got the solution as, there are two approaches to achieve this concept.

Using

```
"Achartengine" or

"kiCharts" approach
```

As per the search every one is recommending to use "Achartengine approach" because it is fully open source, this is the official [link](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list) to this approach that I found.

Then I downloaded that file from the above link and I imported it into Eclipse but its not supporting.  When I am trying to run that project it's showing like the below images.[image][image]
[image]

Even though if I try to do access or while clicking any options on the emulator (here shown in the second image) it's showing up the with same result as **"sorry your app unexpectedly closed!.  Please try again.  Force Close"**

I don't know whether I am going in a wright way or not.

Can any one please explain this concept by sending at least one example program done using the AChartEngine approach.

**OR**

Please at least send me the steps to create a **BAR-CHART** using the AChartEngine approach.

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828616/can-any-one-suggest-me-some-good-tutorials-on-achartengine-for-android-developme) for finding out how to find AChartEngine tutorials. Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160778/the-application-achartengine-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again/10496375#10496375) may help you with the problem that I think you have in setting up the AChartEngine demo.