# I can't run chart on my device

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I've been using achartengine-0.7.0.jar library to make a chart on my project, it's running normally on the emulator, but when I make apk of my project and install it on my device, it is not working, The chart didn't show (error), could anyone help me?

Do i must copy/move/install achartengine-0.7.0.jar library into my device?

Comment: What do you mean with _error_?

Comment: In that case could you please post LogCat logs explaining the Exception you're facing. And no, you should not install ``achartengine-0.7.0.jar`` separately on your device but it should be bundled with application APK.

Comment: well, when i run the chart on my emulator, there's no error at all, so in my logCat only shown starting activity and displayed activity, but when i tried to run in my device, it's force closed :(

Comment: Still, if you have your device connected to Eclipse (assuming that's what you use for development) you should see logs from the device too. Especially the error causing a crash in this case.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160778/the-application-achartengine-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again/10496375#10496375 Also, the logcat logs will help us see what is going on. We also suggest you upgrade to AChartEngine 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is placement of achartengine-0.7.0.jar library :

You should better place it in `libs` or `lib` folder present in the workspace of that project.
so now after placing it in `lib` folder u export to form a `APK file` it will work.