# Could not find class 'org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer'

Tags: android, eclipse, achartengine

During runtime on Android emulator I got the error this error:

Could not find class 'org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer'

I have already added achartengine library to Eclipse.
1.  Add aachartengine-0.7.0.jar  to lib folder int the project.
2.  Added the Jar in Java Build Path to the library.

It compiles fine, but during runtime it could not find the chartengine class.

Comment: check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10496375/996313

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the correct solution.